# How to remove "bootdiagnostics" container from storage blob when deleting Azure VM?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-diagnostics

I'm tasked with automating the creation of Azure VM's, and naturally I do a number of more or less broken iterations of trying to deploy a VM image.

I just discovered that my storage account's blob service is collecting a looong list of containers for boot diagnostics.

Because I've deleted many of the VM's these belong to, these containers are all useless to me, and in the portal they crowd out the few useful folders I do want. In fact, I have a script to destroy VM's (which removes the resources, VHD, and so on); I want this script to also kill these diagnostics containers.

But the containers have very awkward names -- and only contain part of the hostname ...

- How can I, from Powershell, identify the diagnostics container belonging to a specific VM, so that I can delete it along with the other resources?
- Why does Azure not handle this more elegantly, why do I have to "discover" that diagnostics containers and VHD's are not removed when you remove a VM? Is there simply yet another button or screen that I'm not aware of?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the UUID is part of the name of the "status" file (which I have no idea what does) that lives alongside the OS VHD file!

```
function getUUID([string] $vmname) {
    $storageContext = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccount | Where-Object{$_.StorageAccountName -match $azureStorage}).Context
    $storageBlob = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Context $storageContext -Container "vhds"
    $vhdList = $storageBlob | Where-Object{$_.Name -match "$vmname"} | Where-Object{$_.Name -match "^$hostname.*\.status$"}
    $uuid = $vhdList.Name # Get name including UUID
    $uuid = $uuid -replace "\.status","" # Remove suffix (".status")
    $uuid = $uuid -replace ".*?\.","" # Remove prefix ("bootdiagnostics-$vmname.")
    return $uuid
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on my cursory look, bootdiagnostic Storage container names may only contain part of the VM names for names > 8 characters. However, the last part of the container name, the part of name right after your VM name, is the unique identifier of your VM. You can retrieve the Unique Identifier Name of your VM by using the steps mentioned in the following article: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/accessing-and-using-azure-vm-unique-id/. For ARM VMs, you can retrieve the unique identifier of your VM name via REST.

If can then parse the bootdiagnostic storage container name string to obtain the unique identifier of the VM to find out which VMs are using which blob storage containers.

Thanks,
Aung

Comment: Thank you! This sounds very promising, I will try it out as soon as I can and report back.

Comment: So basically `$UUID = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_ComputerSystemProduct -namespace root\CIMV2` from _within_ the VM. But what if I'm _not_ within the VM, but on a remote system, using Azure Powershell to query?

Comment: according to 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/46308a1d-d3c4-4607-9c75-9633c347def6/azure-vm-unique-id-is-not-exposed-through-rest-api?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows 

We cannot get a VM's unique identifier via REST